# Display Merged PDF Files

Tags: vba, excel, macros

is there a way to display/publish the merged pdf file after running the excel vba macro to merge them? OpenAfterPublish:= True doesn't seem to work?

Comment: What do you mean by merged pdf file?

Comment: i have a macro that merges 3 of my pdf files. after merging, i want it to be displayed instead of opening the destination folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open files in excel-vba like

```
Sub test()
Dim myShell As Object
Set myShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
myShell.Run "C:\test.pdf" //replace with your path
End Sub
```

Comment: it gives me an error: Method 'Run' of object 'IWshShell3' failed.

Comment: be sure that yo have no blank spaces in your path

Comment: but it still doesn't work even if there's no spaces in my path. gives me the same error message.